# Stating That Questions Are Mostly Technical

Tags: questions, technical

How to put it right? In this comment clause, we have to admit that the issues are technical, but we have to invite the international experts to resolve it:

**'While these are mostly technical questions, we shall have to invite the international experts to resolve them'.**

Comment: this is one of the final sentences in a letter. The author admits that questions they refer above are technical (more of a logistic nature), and asks for advice of the foreign experts.

Answer (score 6):

You would say "Since" rather than "while".

"While" has almost the opposite meaning to what you want in this context: it implies that the experts aren't a good choice to answer the question but you're obliged to ask them anyway.

Comment: Also, what I wanted to imply here was not that 'experts are not a good choice', but 'due to technicality of issues it may not be a good idea to discuss them with industry experts, but we have to do that anyway, because we are not in a position to make decisions on our own'. Sorry for the late response and thank you for the feedback.

Comment: "since" still works in that situation I think.